# css add spacing between columns

Tags: html, css

I have four columns and I am trying to add space between them but when I put padding into the css the columns are still close and the padding is added within the columns. What am I doing wrong.

```css
/* Create four columns of equal width */
.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    opacity: .8;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
        <div class="columns">
          <%= image_tag("sign-up.ico", align: "center", class:"ico") %>
          <h5>Sign-Up</h5></br>
          <p>Create A <u>FREE</u> Account to make rent payments to your landlord</p>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
          <%= image_tag("cash_wallet.ico", class:"ico") %>
          <h5>Make your rent payments</h5></br>
          <p>Make rent payments thru your LikeHome account & we report history to all 3 credit bureaus</p>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
          <%= image_tag("piggy_bank.ico", align: "center", class:"ico") %>
          <h5>Pay a little extra</h5></br>
          <p>You choose an additional payment amount (as low as $25 per month) to be drafted with your rent that goes into escrow</p>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
          <%= image_tag("handshake.ico", align: "center", class:"ico") %>
          <h5>Get qualified</h5></br>
          <p>The extra money will be held by LikeHome and when ready, we will notify you that you qualify for a mortgage. Use your down payment savings to buy!</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Confused. Padding is always inside an element. If you want space between the elements you need to add margin.

Comment: But of course! Duh, that got it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding is always added inside elements. While your code is correct and does add padding space inside your element, if you want space in between your elements you will need to add margin.

```
.element {
margin:0 2.5%;
width:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**February/2022 Update**

The `grid-column-gap` property is deprecated. You should now use `column-gap`.

__

You may have a better experience using CSS Grid. Adjusting the spacing between columns using a property like `grid-column-gap` seems more intuitive than using `margin`. About the `fr` unit, from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

> The fr unit allows you to set the size of a track as a fraction of the free space of the grid container.

```css
.column {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">column data</div>
  <div class="column">column data</div>
  <div class="column">column data</div>
  <div class="column">column data</div>
</div>
```